# Should the Following Question be Flagged?

Tags: discussion

I came across [Pointers, Classes, Virtual Functions, and Abstract Classes, Dynamic Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28904460/4342498) today.  There isn't really a question and the person just wants code to finish what is apparently homework.  Should this be flagged and if so what flag should be used?

Comment: Probably a good half of the close reasons that exist apply to that question.  Take your pick.

Comment: The custom close reason specified really shouldn't have been used though (I realize you weren't the one that first wrote it); that's not a reason to close the question (after all, there can be perfectly acceptable SO questions that are about homework), it should have just been a regular comment at most.

Comment: It's a better question than some. After reading 'Write a class (largeIntgers) that supports the following functionalities', you can go straight to downCloseVote without reading the rest.  Many assignment questions are heavily disguised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions like that are good candidates to be closed for being either too broad or unclear as to what is being asked.

In the *general* case, though, questions that are poor should simply be downvoted.  The system has measures in place to automatically clean up questions that are downvoted with relatively low views.

Comment: ... as long as they are not answered...